# Post at specific time

Tags: botframework

It there a way to make your bot post to a channel at a specific time?

As an example it could post "Good morning!" every day at 8 am. I'm just wondering if that is possible without webjobs or something like that, I can't really find anything on the documentation about the MS Bot Framework

Answer (score 0):

BotFramework does not have native support for anything like this, but it's pretty easy to do with [Azure Scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/)

Comment: Please, can you explain a little more?